# Having trouble selecting elements in CSS with elements created in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, syntax

I created some divs with JS like so:

```
const container = document.querySelector('#container');
for(let i = 1; i < 17; i++) {
    var row = document.createElement('div');
    row.id = 'r' + i;
    row.class = 'row';
    container.appendChild(row);
    for(let j = 1; j < 17; j++) {
        var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        newDiv.id = 'c' + j;
        newDiv.class = 'box';
        newDiv.textContent = row.id;
        row.appendChild(newDiv);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to test the row divs by adding a border to each row class in css like so:

```
#row {
    border: 1px solid green;

}
```

My question is how come the rows are not showing up with a green border? Am I able to select element from CSS file with elements created in JS?

I was expecting 16 boxes for each of the 16 div elements with class "row".

Comment: `#row` should be `.row` to match the class. `#` is for ID.

Answer (score 2):

1. In the JS use `className` instead of `class`.

```js
row.className = 'row'
```

2. In the CSS use a `.` (the `#` is an id selector)

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues here...

The first issue is in css, to call a class to style in css you must use the `.` selector, so to select the `row` class and give it the style, you need to do this:

```
.row{
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

---

The second issue is in javascript.

JavaScript doesn't have a property called `class` for the DOM elements, but instead it has two other things to work woth the classes, one is the `className` property which is just a string that you must handle by yourself when you try to edit it.

And the code in this case will be like that':

```
row.className = 'row'
```

And the second is the `classList` object which has many useful methods like the `add`, `remove`, and the `contains` methods, that make it very easy to add, remove and check for foundation of multiple classes in javascript.

And the code in your case will be:

```
row.classList.add('row')
```

Then when you need to remove it you can just use this code:

```
row.classList.remove('row')
```

And anytime you try to do some code based on the class foundation, you can check for foundation using this code:

```
if( row.classList.contains('row') ) {
    // Your code here
}
```

---

I hope i managed to help.